Add quote for pyspark dataframe column with regular expressions
I have below column within dataframe
tuff,1,2,3,bp123,5,6,7,jatin gupta ,ext,20021988

I require to use regular expression within pyspark to add double quote after 8 comma ( if double quote not present already) and add ending double quote before digits 20021988
Expected output:
tuff,1,2,3,bp123,5,6,7,"jatin gupta ,ext",20021988

I have tried with below pattern but doesnt work
data = [("TUFF,2,3,BP4,5,6,7,JATIN GUPTA, EXT, 20021988",)]
columns = ["input_string"]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Use regular expression to add quotes after the 7th comma and before the 8 digits
df = df.withColumn("output_string", regexp_replace(col("input_string"), r"((?:[^,]*,){7})([^,]*,[^,]*),([^,]*)", r'\1"\2", \3'))


is regex a requirement? can you do it in another way?

This will do the trick:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn(
    "res", 
    F.regexp_replace(
        F.col("input_string"),
        r"(([^,]*,){7})(.*),([^,]*)",
        r"$1\"$3\",$4",
    )
)

result:
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|input_string                                 |res                                            |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|TUFF,2,3,BP4,5,6,7,JATIN GUPTA, EXT, 20021988|TUFF,2,3,BP4,5,6,7,"JATIN GUPTA, EXT", 20021988|
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+

Few notes:

Group reference in spark is achieved through dollar sign, not slash (I can think of several systems where it's similar - worth generalizing, that it's not always slash)
You have pretty complex definition, containing complete cell - I'd avoid lookahead and lookback regex operators - just define complete cell in groups, then work on individual groups.
Utilize fact that regex is greedy on default - i.e. group to be included within quotes can be treated as whatever terminated with single comma, and whatever except comma.


Thank you very much , Its works as expected , May I know what do mean here  with r"$1"$3",$4",

This is absolutely next level - Still could not understand how $2 is captured and why it is empty...Can you please explain ?

@GouravJoshi $1 is all the string from beginning till the 7th comma, $3 is everything after the 7th comma till the last comma $4 is everything from last comma till the end. $3 is quoted as you requested - I did not understand what $2 would be...
